# attribute rendered is not working properly with Primefaces 3.5 fileupload

Tags: jsf, primefaces

My aim is to hide the upload component after the `fileUpload` is succeeded in PrimeFaces v3.5. Below is the snippet of view-

```
<h:form>
<!-- Here are some more components of PrimeFaces, So i am not updating the entire form-->
    <p:fileUpload id="fileUpload"
        rendered="#{!fileUploadController.hidden}"
        label="Choose Script to upload here"
        style="font-size: 100% !important;" showButtons="false"
        fileUploadListener="#{fileUploadController.upload}"
        mode="advanced" auto="true" sizeLimit="100000"
        allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(py|txt)$/" update="fileUpload" />
<!-- Here are some more components of PrimeFaces, So i am not updating the entire     
</h:form>
```

My `Managed Bean` is below-

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;
import org.primefaces.event.FileUploadEvent;
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class FileUploadController implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    // private String destination = null;
    private String destination = "D:/temp";
    private boolean hidden = false;
    public FileUploadController() {
//      System.out.println("destination=" + destination);
    }
    // private String destination = "D:/download";
    public void upload(FileUploadEvent event) {
        String fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(event.getFile().getFileName());
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
                "Success! ", fileName + " is uploaded.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        try {
            System.out.println("I am trying to copy it...");
            copyFile(fileName, event.getFile().getInputstream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void copyFile(String fileName, InputStream in) {
        try {
            System.out.println("filename= " + fileName + ", dest="
                    + destination);
            // write the inputStream to a FileOutputStream
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(destination
                    + File.separator + fileName));
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            in.close();
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            System.out.println("New file created!");
            setHidden(true);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("ERROR " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    /**
     * @return the hidden
     */
    public boolean isHidden() {
        return hidden;
    }
    /**
     * @param hidden
     *            the hidden to set
     */
    public void setHidden(boolean hidden) {
        this.hidden = hidden;
    }
}
```

File upload is finished successfully but `fileUpload` is not hiding.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't ajax-update a component which is by itself conditionally rendered. The JSF ajax engine JavaScript doesn't add/remove the update target in the HTML DOM tree, instead it replaces the update target in the HTML DOM tree. If the JSF component is not rendered, then the JSF ajax engine would not get anything to replace with. You have instead to ajax-update a parent which is always rendered. You can use among others a `<h:panelGroup>` for it.

```
<h:panelGroup id="fileUploadGroup">
    <p:fileUpload id="fileUpload"
        rendered="#{!fileUploadController.hidden}"
        ...
        update="fileUploadGroup" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks BalusC. It works!!! You know all the hack man... You rocks always... thank you so much...

Comment: Big fat Like for that explanation